# Why are modify headers in chrome extension using `declarative_net_request` 's `rule_resources` flaky and inconsistent?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, chrome-declarativenetrequest

The headers get properly modified for requests after installation for some time.
After a while it stops working.
On debugging I found headers are no longer getting modified as per these rules,
Once I reload/reinstall the extension again, it starts working again.

// src/rules/example.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "requestHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "origin",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "https://www.example.com"
        },
        {
          "header": "referer",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "https://www.example.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "example",
      "isUrlFilterCaseSensitive": false,
      "resourceTypes": ["xmlhttprequest", "websocket"]
    }
  }
]
```

// manifest.json:

```
...
...
"permissions":[
    ...
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
    ...
],
...
...
"host_permissions": [
    "https://*.example.com/",
    "wss://*/*"
  ],
  "optional_host_permissions": [
    "https://*/*"
  ],
...
...
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_example",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "src/rules/example.json"
      }
    ]
  },
...
...
```

The request I am debugging indeed have `example` in url name in both cases(ie before and after reloading) and `resourceType` is indeed `websocket` in both cases and entire url is in lowercase. So there is no way the `condition` changed.

And I have only one rule in entire project. So I don't think it is a priority issue either.

I suspect caching issue of some sorts.

Comment: Maybe the site uses a service worker to serve these requests. You'll have to unregister it via browsingData API ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74823389)) and forbid its installation by adding a blocking rule for the URL of the script.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for this wonderful solution. I made the code change but how do I test it ?

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried to implement your code but I am having another issue trying to do so. I have access to `chrome.declarativeNetRequest` but not `chrome.browsingData` . My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58149868/865220) but in my extension I create chrome tabs from `background.js` so I guess permissions should be similar to `background.js`

Comment: @wOxxOm   Ignore last comment. `permissions: [.. "browsingData",..]` was missing, will get back to you.

Comment: Another guess: https://crbug.com/1504862

Comment: @wOxxOm I haven't gotten to the 2nd approach yet. Trying to understand the first one. which origins should I remove from browsingData: `https://example.com` or `chrome-extension://<hash>` or both ? second question is: my rules are statically set right? then why am I not doing `updateStaticRules` instead of `updateSessionRules`?

Comment: There's no updateStaticRules. Just don't use updateSessionRules. Use browsingData with the origin of the site.

Comment: @wOxxOm using `browsingData` alone didn't work either . There aren't any solutions on crbug , moreover from crbug it seems to be a very recent bug. Since which version of chromium are you seeing this?

Comment: I actually don't know what happens in your case, I've just ventured a couple of guesses.

Comment: @wOxxOm that what my question is how to know, I am kind of shooting in the dark as I don't have ideas to figure that out nor simulate the behaviour than to a wait for a couple of days to test.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you tell me what more information should I add to the question to enable my fellow stackoverflowians help be debug better.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes as per the `chrome` object in my chrome dev tools there is no `updateStaticRules `. But that is this [dev docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/declarativeNetRequest#type-UpdateStaticRulesOptions) talking about .

Comment: updateStaticRules is to toggle the rules, not update them, it's just a bad/inappropriate name.